# How can I pass an array values to a class variables in php

Tags: php

I have a function which is inserting multiple rows and I'm getting last inserted id by using the php function ($arr[] = mysqli_insert_id($db);) and it's giving me three last inserted ID. I wanted to pass it to a class variables to put those rows to junction table in mysql.

```
$arrTagID = array($postTag->insertTag());           

foreach ($arrTagID as $tagTD => $ID) {

    $postTag->TagID1 = $ID[0]; 
    $postTag->TagID2 = $ID[1]; 
    $postTag->TagID3 = $ID[2]; 
}

$postTag->post_id = $post_id;
$postTag->insertPostToTag();
```

I have checked the class variables it's giving me null.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to work, as you may need to insert them one by one, BUT the problem with your code is that you are setting the values from `$ID[0]` etc.  and `$ID` is most likely just a single id value.  You may be better off just passing in the array...

```
$postTag->insertPostToTag($arrTagID);
```

and working with that array directly (using the `foreach()` but inside the function.

If you have to stick to your current method, then you would need to do something like...

```
$arrTagID = array($postTag->insertTag());           

$postTag->TagID1 = $arrTagID[0]; 
$postTag->TagID2 = $arrTagID[1]; 
$postTag->TagID3 = $arrTagID[2]; 

$postTag->post_id = $post_id;
$postTag->insertPostToTag();
```

which just extracts the three ID's from the start array and there is no need for the `foreach()`.